# Angular2 ContentChildren has itself as a child

Tags: angular

I have just seen that ContentChildren has itself as a children from this example.

https://plnkr.co/edit/V8t1gR?p=preview

`ngui-react` is just a component selector. You can think it as `my-component`. I use this name for the development of [@ngui/react](https://github.com/ng2-ui/react).

```
  <ngui-react id="0">
    <ngui-react id="10">
      <ngui-react id="11"></ngui-react>
      <ngui-react id="12"></ngui-react>
    </ngui-react>
  </ngui-react>
```

This is the component code that I am running.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngui-react',
  template: `
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>&lt;ngui-react id={{id}}></legend>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  `
})
```

As you seen on this screenshot,
the content  children of ngui-react#11 should be `[]`,
but I see `[11]`, which has it self as children.

It is ver odd to me.

[image]

Is this behaviour by design?, or did I find a bug?

Comment: Seems the same as https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10098